# Using django-cities-light with django-crispy-forms and django-ajax-selects

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-ajax-selects

I need to have a form where user enters name, email and selects a city and country. I am using [django-cities-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light) to populate the database with list of cities and countries.

Then, I create a form using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) using the database model as shown below.

### Models.py

```
from cities_light.models import City, Country

class CustomModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

### Forms.py

```
Class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout.append(ButtonHolder(
            Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

Using this in a view gives me a form with two text fields (for name, email) and two select fields (for city, country). Now, since the number of cities is pretty high, I wish to change these to text fields that use [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) to show names of cities or countries when user starts typing.

A section of [documentation](http://django-cities-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-3.x.x/contrib.html#module-cities_light.contrib.ajax_selects_lookups) provides AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS, but I can't quite understand how to change my form and then connect it with ajax-selects. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

See documentation for django-ajax-selects for django-ajax-selects usage: https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects#quick-installation

Note that @ yourlabs we use django-autocomplete-light now, so it's not really supported anymore, but it's there for users who haven't migrated to django-autocomplete-light yet.